# how to extract (x, y) coordinate value from a grid python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a grid 7x3
how to extract (x, y) coordinate value that contain "1"?

```
grid = np.array([
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,1,0,1,0,1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your array to [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) which will find non-zero values:

```
grid = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
])

np.argwhere(grid)
```

returning

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 6],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 6]])
```

If you need specifically where the array is `1` and not non-zero, you can pass a condition:

```
np.argwhere(grid == 1)
```

giving the same result.